# WooCommerce permalinks

Tags: permalinks, plugins

I got the following question:

When I go to a WooCommerce category, the link displays like this:

```
http://www.example.com/product-category/category/
```

Where the bold text is the link like it is and the rest is the product category that needs to be shown.

When i go into WooCommerce settings and I go to the pages tab, I got an option to change productcategory slugs. If I fill the following in this textfield: `%product_cat%` the links shows as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/category/category/
```

What I want to show in my links is:

```
http://www.example.com/category/subcategory/product
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Answer (score 2):

We use a method simular to this to generate product permalinks: [Custom field values in permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/custom-field-values-in-permalink/3517#3517)

Annoyingly this supports one level of category only - not nested categories, so I believe what you want to do is not possible (but if anyone else has a solution I'd love to hear it!).

Answer (score 2):

There is post on here about [URL rewrites that you can use for woocommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33551/how-to-rewrite-uri-of-custom-post-type/33555#33555) if you want to do something else.

**Product Base Page URL**
You'll also want to tick this option on WooCommerce > Settings > Pages
[image]

This setting is mentioned in the [WooCommerce documentation on Permalinks](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/permalinks/)

Comment: Your second link is a 404.