# Add sku to product url woocommerce

Tags: permalinks, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to make url's with the following structure:

```
www.mywebsite.com/wordpress/product/postname-sku
```

for example:

```
 wordpress/product/apple-ap01
```

Is this possible?

And also tell if this done with .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

looks like this will do what you want just write out a custom function for it: 
[Custom field values in permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/custom-field-values-in-permalink/3517#3517)

something like this: as the link says:

```
function jpb_custom_meta_permalink( $link, $post ){
  $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '<insert your meta key here>', true );
  if( empty( $post_meta ) || !is_string( $post_meta ) )
    $post_meta = '<insert your default value (could be an empty string) here>';
  $link = str_replace( '!!custom_field_placeholder!!', $post_meta, $link );
  return $link;
}

add_filter( 'post_link', 'jpb_custom_meta_permalink', 10, 2 );
```

you can hash the url and use this:

```
function append_sku_string( $link, $post ) {
  $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_sku', true );
      if ( 'product' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        $link = $link . '#' .$post_meta;
        return $link;
     }
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'append_sku_string', 1, 2 );
```

which will return http://example.com/product/productname#sku

Comment: this may be a stupid question, but where do i need to put this code / call the function?

Comment: Please add some code/explanation to your answer. If that link ever dies your answer won't be helpful any longer.

Comment: @Jonasvermeulen in your themes function's file will do it...1

Comment: it works, but this hooks to 'post_link', so it works only for posts, how can i hook to woo commerce products?

Comment: technically woocommerce products are custom post types...

Comment: technically it is. but it only works for normal posts :-( do you have an idea how to get it working for woorcommerce products as well?

Comment: let's see what we can russle up