# Add only sku to product url woocoomerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks

I'm referring to following question:

[Add sku to product url woocommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/146143/add-sku-to-product-url-woocommerce)

The user was looking for a solution to add the SKU to the URL. This also works with the described variant. However, I need it in a different form. I want my URL to look like this.

http://example.com/product/sku

Does anyone know how the code would need to be rewritten to achieve this result?

Thank you!

Comment: How about typing  like `product/sku_id` then redirect to `product/product_name`? It works in your scenario.If this solution fit to you, setup the action hook `template_redirect` would works.

Comment: Other choice , keep the code and explode the URI , pop product name then implode. then pu the SKU_ID into the link. But it's not recommended to change wordpress router like that.